# The use of adjective + noun between as and as

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

I woul like to ask whether the following sentence is correct:
“Tourism plays as an important role as export in determing economic growth”
Is it possible to use adjective + noun between as and as

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This sort of expression has two somewhat different constructions; in neither does the compared adjective immediately precede its head.

1. The more common construction puts the compared adjective before the determinate noun phrase it modifies:

   > Tourism plays as important a role as export [plays] in . . .
2. The more formal construction puts the entire comparative construction after the determinate noun phrase it modifies:

   > Tourism plays a role as important as export [plays] in . . .

The bracketed element may be omitted, and usually is.